# Connection error from Deployer to ActiveMQ service for Sites 9.1

Tags: deployer, sites-9.1, activemq

I installed the ActiveMQ service on the deployer server for sites 9.1 for enabling caching and made configuration changes in the **cd_storage_conf.xml** file for ActiveMQ. ActiveMQ service seems to be working fine and port 61616 is listening but on deployer, side getting below error:

> Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616?soTimeout=5000.
> Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection
> refused)

Here are the changes I made in the deployer config. Can anybody suggest what might be the issue and if I'm missing anything?

```
<ObjectCache Enabled="true">
 <Policy Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy" Type="LRU">
    <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
 </Policy>
 <Features>
    <Feature Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker" Type="DependencyTracker"/>
 </Features>

<RemoteSynchronization>
<Connector Class="com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector" Topic="Tridion">
                 <JndiContext>
                   <Property Name="java.naming.factory.initial" Value="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
                   <Property Name="java.naming.provider.url" Value="tcp://localhost:61616?soTimeout=5000"/>
                   <Property Name="topic.Tridion" Value="TridionCCS"/>  
                 </JndiContext>
   </Connector>
 </RemoteSynchronization>
```

Comment: which version of DXD? Is it for sites or docs?

Comment: Is that all the time happens or very often happens? Is that deployer / ActiveMQ restart not helpful?

Comment: Its sites 9.1. And installed activeMQ just now and it didn't worked even once. i restarted both deployer and activeMQ but didn't helped

Comment: Are that deployer and ActiveMQ running on the same server? try access this ActiveMQ admin console to see your Tridion topic created and also check the subscriber channels to see your deployer hostname appears or not http://localhost:8161/admin

Comment: Yes, deployer and ActiveMQ are on same server. Accessed the admin console and there are no tridion topics created and subscriber view not showing deployer hostnames. As i see connection error in cd_cache log file, that might be the reason topics are not getting delivered from deployer to activeMQ.

Comment: Either your ActiveMQ installation something went wrong, maybe worth try - un-install and re-install to see. which version of ActiveMQ you have installed?

Comment: If you're running ActiveMQ on Windows then you can configure this in wrapper.conf, this config file can be found in the ActiveMQ root directory bin/win64 and bin/win32 folders.
wrapper.java.additional.13=-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES="*"                                    
  Verify that the RemoteSynchronization element is uncommented and details are correct in the cd_storage_conf.xml file of the Deployer and Session Content services as well.

Comment: okay, @Velmurugan: i installed ActiveMQ version 5.15.9 based on jar files version at location Sites 9.1\Content Delivery\roles\deployer\deployer-combined\standalone\services\activemq.I hope thats correct. Also, i downloaded tar file for 5.15.9 version directly from ActiveMQ site so i hope thats the correct file to use. And just to confirm, Even if content service side is having issue communicating with activeMQ service installed on deployer server(deployer and Content service are on different servers) then am i right in assuming that atleast deployer should be able to send message to activemq?

Comment: check out this link may help you https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000004492 and change java provider url value to tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?soTimeout=5000 restart deployer service

Comment: Perhaps the simplest suggestion: have you tried connecting to localhost port 61616 with telnet from the machine where the deployer is installed?

Comment: It seems communication started today temporarily between Deployer and activeMQ after adding <Property Name="trustAllPackages" Value="true" /> in cd storage config. i could see subscription as well as enqueue dequeue count in web console. But communication stopped again after some time with deployer logs again giving error for connection  issue.